# Angular "Tour of Heroes" Tutorial -- Router Not Found

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

While trying to do the Angular tutorial, I have run in to a lot of issues trying to do the router section. At first I couldn't get it to compile at all and it said it couldn't find the router, leading me to try upgrading to the 3.0.0 alpha and other potential solutions I can't even remember. Eventually I got it compiling, but when I try and view the page, all I get is the default "Loading..." text indefinitely and a console error in the JS console:

```
localhost/:18 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/router(…)(anonymous function) @ localhost/:18
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/router.umd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

My index.html looks like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>My lil' tour o' 'roes</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
  System.import('router').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); }); <!-- LINE 18 -->
</script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

And my package.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

I'm new to web development and don't know what other files/info would be helpful, but will attempt to update the post with whatever people suggest. I am running on OS X (El Capitan 10.11.5), developing in Visual Studio Code and using Vivaldi (Chrome-based) as my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Angular moved all of their modules into a `bundles` subdirectory ([see the breaking changes for rc.2 here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)). In your system.config, you'll need to map the router package to that directory:

```
var packages = {
  /* Other packages..*/
  '@angular/router': { main: 'bundles/router.umd', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```